# Business Intelligence: What are the most importants APIs to build a Java BB application?

Tags: java, business-intelligence

I need to make an application about Java Business Intelligence APIs and I need to exemplify one open-source version and one proprietary version.

Could you tell which one you thing I should take in consideration?

Comment: You might need to explain yourself better. I'm completely confused.

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming Q&A site. Unless you are in need of programming help, you're in the wrong place. This isn't a forum to ask people to nominate websites for your presentation.

Comment: Look here, there is a list with Open Source Business Intelligence Tools Written in Java: http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-java-business-intelligence . Which one should I consider? Which is most used in the industry? What about the proprietary tools?

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

- [Mondrian](http://community.pentaho.com/projects/mondrian/) –  is an OLAP server written in Java. Mondrian provides
  the interactive ability to analyze very large datasets stored in SQL
  databases without having to write SQL. Mondrian is used for
  multi-dimensional exploration of data. It supports the translation of
  Multi-Dimensional eXpression (MDX) language into SQL.
- [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/project/notable2.2.php#jump_2) - offers dynamic cross table and data cube elements. The
  data cube element appears in the Data Explorer view and allows the
  developer to build cubes based on existing data sets. Earlier
  versions of BIRT required that the number of columns had to be known
  beforehand.
- [Pentaho BI Suite](http://www.pentaho.com/) –  The Pentaho project provides a Business
  Intelligence suite that includes reporting, analysis, dashboards,
  data mining and data integration capabilities. The software offers a
  flexible and comprehensive infrastructure to build customizable BI
  application solutions.